# Does scaling a canvas affect the number of pixels getDataURL() returns?

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm experimenting with using a canvas as an image cropping preview and then use `getDataUrl()` to retrive the data to send to the server via an AJAX post.

I've explicitly set the initial width and height of the canvas in the HTML using pixels, but I scale the canvas using percentages in CSS to fit a responsive design.

While it would make sense that scaling a canvas element wouldn't affect the pixel content, I'd like to be certain. Will scaling a canvas element, not its content, return a different number of pixels than what I initially set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, scaling the canvas with CSS do not affect the actual pixels it contains.

You can look at the canvas as an image, it can be stretched but the actual pixels in the source image will be the same.